# Invoke Page's Codebehind method from Sublayout in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, repeater, sitecore6

I'm trying to invoke the page's code behind method from the repeater control which is actual in the sublayout.

### Problem

The `sc:fieldrenderer` works good and renders on the page source but `<%# method(data) %>` does not seems to be working and prints as it is on the page source.

### Description

I have downloaded sitecore package from here - **[Sitecore jQuery Content Slider](http://www.fuseit.com/en/FuseITBlog/2012/June/Sitecore%20jQuery%20Content%20Slider.aspx)** which provides [zip sitecore installation](http://downloads.fuseit.com/FreeDownloads/FuseITContentSlider-1.2.zip)

And the repeater syntax is somewhat like this

**Sublayout (partial) syntax**

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="repeater">
<itemtemplate>
    <li>
        <div style="background: url("
            <%# GetImageUrl(Container.DataItem) %>); height:
            <%# Height %>px;">

            <div style="padding:"
                <%# GetTopMargin(Container.DataItem) %>px 0px 0px
                <%# GetLeftMargin(Container.DataItem) %>px; width:
                <# GetTextWidth(Container.DataItem) %>px; text-align:
                <%# GetTextAlignment(Container.DataItem) %>;">
                <div class="title">
                    <sc:fieldrenderer fieldname="Title" item=''
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"></sc:fieldrenderer>
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <sc:fieldrenderer fieldname="Text" item=''
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"></sc:fieldrenderer>
                </div>

                <div class="link">
                    <sc:fieldrenderer fieldname="URL" item=''
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"></sc:fieldrenderer>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
</itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

**Sublayout code behind**

```
    public string GetImageUrl(object itm)
    {
        Item item = (Item)itm;
        ImageField image = item.Fields["Image"];

        if (image != null)
        {
            MediaItem i = image.MediaItem;

            if (i == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;    
            }

            string u = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(i);

            u = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(u);

            return string.Concat("", u);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

### Output

```
<div style="background: url(<%# GetImageUrl(Container.DataItem) %>); height:<%# Height %>px;">

<div style="padding:"<%# GetTopMargin(Container.DataItem) %>px 0px 0px <%# GetLeftMargin(Container.DataItem) %>px; width: <# GetTextWidth(Container.DataItem) %>px; text-align:<%# GetTextAlignment(Container.DataItem) %>;">
    <div class="title">
        Untitled Item
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="link">
        <a title="Lorem-Ipsum">Learn about Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

### Expected output

The server tag such as `<%# GetImageUrl(Container.DataItem) %>` and similar should resolve to the value from the page behind method. I have tried my ways but not able to make this workable.. I have even tried to comment and uncomment the `typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded` in the web.config for repeater `<type>System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater</type>`

### Question

> How to solve the **Problem** here or I should change to repeater `ItemDataBound` event and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, databinding this way is bad design.
What I would do (and you will definitely solve your "problem" if you do this) is use `FindControl` in the `ItemDataBound` event of the repeater and bind your data to the found controls.

Instead of DIV elements you can use `asp:Panel` controls and set the `Style` property on them (although I highly suggest you use CSS classes to keep it maintainable)

If someone could format this answer, would be appreciated (using mobile device)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered and accepted, but you also have a typo:

```
<# GetTextWidth(Container.DataItem) %>px; text-align:
```

should be

```
<%# GetTextWidth(Container.DataItem) %>px; text-align:
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I found those mistakes afterwards and as I fixed this and other such typo it got working. The downloaded package was not working out of the box.. ;)